# Add ASCII image

Tags: verbatim

I want to add many ASCIIs Art images on my document. But If I use verbatim environment, the output is ugly !

[image]

How to solve?
(I lovely a solution with the possibility to import only my txt file with ascii image in my tex file)

ascii file

```
                                                           Monde de l'ordinateur
   Monde réel           Monde conceptuel          +--------------------------------------+
                                                  |                                      |
                                                  |                          .-------.   |
+--------------+        +--------------+          |+--------------+         /         \  |
|              |        |              |          ||              |        (           ) |
|    Objets    |        |   Entités    |          ||    Tables    |        |`.       ,'| |
|  Propriétés  |------->| Associations |---------->|   Schémas    |------> |    Base   | |
|   Valeurs    |        |  Attributs   |          ||  Attributs   |        |     de    | |
|              |        |              |          ||              |        |  données  | |
+--------------+        +--------------+          |+--------------+        (           ) |
                                |                 |        |                `.       ,'  |
                                |                 |        |                  `-----'    |
                                |                 +--------+---------------------+-------+
                                |                          |                     |
                                v                          v                     v
                      +------------------+          +-------------+       +-------------+
                      |   Modélisation   |          |Modélisation |       |Modélisation |
                      | conceptuelle des |          | logique des |       |physique des |
                      |     données      |          |   données   |       |   données   |
                      +------------------+          +-------------+       +-------------+
```

.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt, french, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}

                                                              Monde de l'ordinateur          
    Monde réel           Monde conceptuel         +--------------------------------------+
                                                  |                                      |
                                                  |                          .-------.   |
+--------------+        +--------------+          |+--------------+         /         \  |
|              |        |              |          ||              |        (           ) |
|    Objets    |        |   Entités    |          ||    Tables    |        |`.       ,'| |
|  Propriétés  |------->| Associations |---------->|   Schémas    |------> |    Base   | |
|   Valeurs    |        |  Attributs   |          ||  Attributs   |        |     de    | |
|              |        |              |          ||              |        |  données  | |
+--------------+        +--------------+          |+--------------+        (           ) |
                                  |               |        |                `.       ,'  |
                                  |               |        |                  `-----'    |
                                  |               +--------+---------------------+-------+
                                  |                        |                     |        
                                  v                        v                     v        
                     +------------------+          +-------------+       +-------------+ 
                     |   Modélisation   |          |Modélisation |       |Modélisation | 
                     | conceptuelle des |          | logique des |       |physique des | 
                     |     données      |          |   données   |       |   données   | 
                     +------------------+          +-------------+       +-------------+ 


\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add an MWE? Btw, I really think you should draw the figure yourself, using something like Ti*k*Z or PSTricks.

Comment: Welcome! Please, show the code, nobody here is going to retype it based on the image.

Comment: @JouleV what's MWE?

Comment: @The33Coder [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156344) (minimal working example) is a compilable code snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: With `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: You should use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} \usepackage[french]{babel}` instead.

Comment: Are you OK with the Computer Modern Monospaced typeface? Or would you rather use a typeface such as Courier? Please advise.

Comment: With courier font is better, but I have the half image outside !

Comment: do you have tabs in the file? I see no other reason why your ascii boxes should be out of line? all tabs are converted to spaces on this site so try the file as posted here , which has no tabs,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no I have space. With Courier font the image is correctly displaying. But they are little big and the half image is outside from page.

Comment: put `\small` before the verbatim

Comment: You could do the world a favor and convert these "art works" into a graphic based format (unless this is a report on art history).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a smaller font size:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.art}
    Monde réel           Monde conceptuel         +--------------------------------------+
                                                  |                                      |
                                                  |                          .-------.   |
+--------------+        +--------------+          |+--------------+         /         \  |
|              |        |              |          ||              |        (           ) |
|    Objets    |        |   Entités    |          ||    Tables    |        |`.       ,'| |
|  Propriétés  |------->| Associations |---------->|   Schémas    |------> |    Base   | |
|   Valeurs    |        |  Attributs   |          ||  Attributs   |        |     de    | |
|              |        |              |          ||              |        |  données  | |
+--------------+        +--------------+          |+--------------+        (           ) |
                                  |               |        |                `.       ,'  |
                                  |               |        |                  `-----'    |
                                  |               +--------+---------------------+-------+
                                  |                        |                     |        
                                  v                        v                     v        
                     +------------------+          +-------------+       +-------------+ 
                     |   Modélisation   |          |Modélisation |       |Modélisation | 
                     | conceptuelle des |          | logique des |       |physique des | 
                     |     données      |          |   données   |       |   données   | 
                     +------------------+          +-------------+       +-------------+ 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt, french, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{center}
\BVerbatimInput[fontsize=\scriptsize]{\jobname.art}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to show that you can use an external file. I named it `\jobname.art` just not to risk clobbering my files.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> [image: mwe]

You could improve these diagrams a bit using an ASCII to SVG converter and then convert it to PDF to use as a simple image. I never made it before, but with [asciitosvg-grid](https://github.com/jczimm/asciitosvg-grid) and your sample the result is not perfect but promising. Your mileage may vary with other diagrams and maybe with other similar tools.

I changed a bit the original:

```
                                                      Monde de l'ordinateur
   Monde réel           Monde conceptuel          .--------------------------------------.
                                                  |                                      |
                                                  |                          .-------.   |
.--------------.        .--------------.          |.--------------.         /         \  |
|              |        |              |          ||              |        .           . |
|    Objets    |        |   Entités    |          ||    Tables    |        |` ------- ´| |
|  Propriétés  +------->| Associations +---------->|   Schémas    |------> |    Base   | |
|   Valeurs    |        |  Attributs   |          ||  Attributs   |        |     de    | |
|              |        |              |          ||              |        |  données  | |
.--------------.        .-----+--------.          |.-------+------.        .           . |
                              |                   |        |                \         /  |
                              |                   |        |                 .-------.   |
                              |                   .--------+---------------------+-------.
                              v                            |                     |
                                                           |                     v
                      .------------------.          .----- v ------.       .--------------.
                      |                  |          |              |       |              | 
                      |   Modélisation   |          | Modélisation |       | Modélisation |
                      | conceptuelle des |          |  logique des |       | physique des |
                      |     données      |          |   données    |       |   données    |
                      |                  |          |              |       |              | 
                      .------------------.          .--------------.       .--------------.
```

... in order to produce rounded boxes and avoid and put the three vertical arrowheads at different heights (otherwise first two are lost, it seems a converter bug). Minor pitfalls like add some arrowhead can be fixed manually editing the pdf in Inkscape with minor efforts, but the showed here is the original without any retouch.

The code of the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, french, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo.pdf}}
\section*{Instructions}
\begin{verbatim}

    $ asciitosvg < foo.txt > foo.svg

    $ inkscape foo.svg --export-pdf=foo.pdf

\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your approach is very interesting because I want to add svg images too